# How can I resize of scrollbar in UItoolkit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

In ScrollView, scrollbar's size is not changed. I tried to edit scrollbar's size. but it can't access.

I was expended #unity-content-container and insert the GroupBox. i expected scrollbar's size is fallow the #unity-content-container. but it was not changed. i also tried that every component. scrollbar was not changed. how can i fix it?

Comment: the scrollbar is automatically resized.

Answer (score 0):

I tried altering some of the styles as well and they did not seem to make much difference.  You can use the UI debugger to see which elements are controlling the styles.

One way to absolutely do but may take a bit of work is to unpack it, make the changes, and then save it to a custom component.  It is work upfront, but it will let you reuse you styled scroll bars wherever you need.